# Mapnik/CartoCSS: make text labels overlap other layers (but not each other)

Tags: mapnik, cartocss

I'm using Mapnik 3.0.7 to render a basemap and a Shapefile layer that contains points. The labels for these points should overlap all the layers underneath, but not each other. Unfortunately, road labels from a lower layer are preventing some of them from being placed:

[image: labels]

I've tried the following:

- Adding `allow-overlap="true"` to the point `TextSymbolizer`, which makes the point labels overlap *everything*, including each other (bad).
- Adding `text-label-position-tolerance` options to the underlying road labels, which I assumed would move them out of the way and allow the point labels to be placed. No effect.
- Various `text-comp-op` options on the point layer and underlying layers, with no effect or undesired effects.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: I think currently it is not possible to do what you want to do. Although you might ask the Mapnik developers at https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik to be sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out a proper solution is described in the [Mapnik Wiki](https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik/wiki/XMLConfigReference#layer). The `Layer` element supports a `clear-label-cache` attribute:

> clear-label-cache: Default "off". Setting this to "on" clears the
>   internal placement detector list, causing the items of this layer, and
>   from this layer on, to be rendered without taking previous rendered
>   items into account ('clear collision avoidance list')

Comment: And it took me a while to figure out how to introduce this attribute in a mll file when working with cartoCSS: `"properties": {"clear-label-cache": "on"},`